# SiteConfigExtension (DataExtension) with onBeforeWrite function in it

Tags: php, silverstripe

I created a DataExtension to extend my SiteConfig.

In my Extension I've got an onBeforeWrite function

```
    public function onBeforeWrite() {
        parent::onBeforeWrite();

        /* FILL SHOP EMAIL FIELDS */
        if(! $this->ShopEmail ){
            $this->ShopEmail = 'foo';
        }

        if(! $this->ShopFromEmail ) {
            $this->ShopFromEmail = $this->ShopEmail;
        }

        if(! $this->ShopReplyEmail ) {
            $this->ShopReplyEmail = $this->ShopEmail;
        }

        /* SHOW ADD TO CART BUTTON IF THERE IS NO ITEMDETAIL PAGE */
        if( $this->ShopItemDetailPage == 0 ) {
            $this->ShopDirectItemToCart = 1;
        }
    }
```

this function just won't work.
With the if-clause I receive a notice wich points me to the first line of the onBeforeWrite function. Without it simply does nothing.

Why is this and how can I solve this?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: that'll be `$this->owner->ShopEmail` since you're in the extension, not the extended class itself...

Comment: Thank you, but why not as answer? ;)

Answer (score 4):

As you're in a `DataExtension`, not `DataObject`, there's a couple of difference to watch out for.

The first, which is the one causing your error, is that there's no `onBeforeWrite` on the parent class, so calling `parent::onBeforeWrite()` is trying to call an undefined method and throwing a fatal error.

The second, which would just cause warnings, is that the database fields aren't defined on `DataExtension`, so you need to use `$this->owner` to access them. For example, `$this->owner->ShopEmail`.

Comment: Thank you! owner solved it. Are your sure with the onBeforeWrite function? Because now it works.

Comment: Yes, he is :). the onbeforewrite etc. functions work without the parent:: part inside the extension code. You don't get an error because the function is defined in the parent class of the DataExtension class. It's an empty function effectively doing nothing, but saving you an error.